# Upgrade from node6.x to node8.x gives "node-saas" binding errors

Tags: node.js

On windows 64 bit platform, upgrade from Node6.x to Node8.x gave the following

```
Error: Missing binding C:\bisbor1\src\main\webapp\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
```

It also asks to build the node-saas library for which it is mandatory to install Python. For a front end developer, it seems a bit bizarre to install Python to run a simple "Hello Angular" app. And funnily, i don't even need node-saas. Its not a direct dependency for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking my head over installing Python to reinstalling "node_modules" several times (never mind the "download" of the internet that 'npm install' demands), I finally found peace with the following solution.

"*Downloaded the appropriate platform specific binding file (note the version of binding in the error thrown) from the git repository*
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

*And updated the node-sass binding in my npm cache which is located at C:\Users\bisbor1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57*"

Answer (score 0):

The Primary step is to ensure that you are having Python 2.7 installed, because `node-gyp` only supports python2, as of writing the post.

To do so:

- check whether Python Version is 2.7 or lower `using python --version`
- downgrade using `sudo apt-get install python`
- then rebuild node-sass using `npm rebuild-node-sass`

If everything else is correct, then a `npm start` would launch your App.